# XAMPP: Problems with ports

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ports

I tried to run XAMPP, but due to some port conflicts I had to change my ports.
When I try to start it now, I get the following message:

```
17:00:07  [Apache]  Problem detected!
17:00:07  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
17:00:07  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
17:00:07  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
17:00:07  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
17:00:07  [Apache]  Problem detected!
17:00:07  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
17:00:07  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
17:00:07  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
17:00:07  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Despite this message, Apache seems to work, even the ports are right:

[image: apache]

Also, I can access it with `http://localhost:8080/`.

So do I have to worry about that message?

Comment: Looks like skype is running in your desktop :) did you check ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the line `listen 80` in httpd.conf to `listen 8080`? This should resolve the error message. As usual restart Apache after the change to apply it.

Ignore that bloke going on about Skype, it's probably IIS/WWW publishing service running in the background (start > run > services.msc and stop the world wide web publishing service if it's running).

The WWW service is now enabled by default in Windows 10 if you've recently installed Xampp on a Windows 10 platform or upgraded your install, I had the same issue.

Comment: FYI, Skype does indeed uses port 80 and 443 as the default ports for incoming connections.

Comment: Yes, it already changed to `Listen 8080`. I think, that's why this port is used in the image I posted.

Comment: Did you ensure you removed the line `listen 80` too rather than having both? @Brian indeed it can except usually Xampp is polite enough to tell you that it's Skype, and it's a configuration change in Skype you have to actually make (not default). I'm running Skype right now with XAMPP and no issues. Besides this is a known issue ("Unable to open process" with PID4) with WWW services running on a WAMP stack and conflicting with Apache.

Comment: I just replaced `80` with `8080`, so I only have 1 line

Comment: @user1170330 did you follow the other part of the post?